# how to invalidate sessions programmatically?

Tags: java, session

I know invalidating a session by setting a time-out period in DD-web.xml file but I like to know how to invalidate sessions programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you programm in java, but the hint of the deplyment descriptor web.xml looks like java. In that case try the following steps:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false); // fetch a reference to the existing session
...
session.invalidate(); // invalidates this session and unbinds any objects bound to it
```

Comment: Ensure null-check if using getSession(false)!

Comment: but how do you invalidate ALL sessions?

Comment: Restart your web server? ;o) j/k, but that would be one way to do it

Answer (score 0):

If in ASP.NET, I think you are looking for [HttpSessionState.Abandon()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon.aspx).

Comment: DD-web.xml makes me think it's java, not asp.net though.

Comment: You're probably right. I've edited to indicate ASP.NET. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in Asp.net

> Session.Abondon()